# Limit choices and validate django's foreign key to related objects (also in REST)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I have my `models.py` like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ...
```

And I want to limit choices of `Category` for `Todo` to only those ones where `Todo.user` = `Category.user`

Every solutuion that I've found was to set queryset for a `ModelForm` or implement method inside a form. (As with `limit_choices_to` it is not possible(?))

The problem is that I have not only one model with such limiting problem (e.g `Tag`, etc.)

Also, I'm using django REST framework, so I have to check `Category` when `Todo` is added or edited.

So, I also need functions `validate` in serializers to limit models right (as it does not call model's `clean`, `full_clean` methods and does not check `limit_choices_to`)

So, I'm looking for a simple solution, which will work for both django Admin and REST framework.

Or, if it is not possible to implement it the simple way, I'm looking for an advice of how to code it the most painless way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I've found so far:

To get `Foreignkey` showed right in admin, you have to specify a form in `ModelAdmin`

```
class TodoAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user__pk=self.instance.user.pk)

@admin.register(Todo)
class TodoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TodoAdminForm
    ...
```

To get `ManyToManyField` showed right in `InlineModelAdmin` (e.g. `TabularInline`) here comes more dirty hack (can it be done better?)

You have to save your quiring field value from object and then manually set queryset in the field. My `through` model has two members `todo` and `tag`

And I'd like to filter `tag` field (pointing to model `Tag`):

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Todo.tags.through

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        request.saved_user_pk = obj.user.pk  # Not sure if it can be None
        return super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'tag':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Tag.objects.filter(user__pk=request.saved_user_pk)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

And finally, to restrict elements only to related in Django REST framework, I have to implement custom `Field`

```
class PrimaryKeyRelatedByUser(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
```

And use it in my serializer like

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = PrimaryKeyRelatedByUser(required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())
    tags = PrimaryKeyRelatedByUser(required=False, many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = ('id', 'category', 'tags', ...)
```

Not sure if it actually working in all cases as planned. I'll continue this small investigation.

Question still remains. Could it be done simplier?